# Keep exact words in the list and remove others

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here I have a list a and I have another list b which includes some strings. And for strings in the list a, I want to keep the ones which appears in the list b. And remove other strings which do not appear in list b.

For example:

```
list_a = [['a','a','a','b','b','b','g','b','b','b'],['c','we','c','c','c','c','c','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b']]
list_b = ['a']
```

The result I expect is:

Get list_a like this: `[['a','a','a'],['a','a','a','a']]`

However, when I run my code:

```
data = [['a','a','a','b','g','b'],['we','c','a','b','a','a','b','a','b']]
keep_words = ['a']
for document in data:
    print('######')
    for word in document:
        print(word)
        if word in keep_words:
            document.remove(word)
            print(document)
print('#####')
print(data)
```

I get this result:

```
line 1:######
line 2:a
line 3:['a', 'a', 'b', 'g', 'b']
line 4:a
line 5:['a', 'b', 'g', 'b']
line 6:g
line 7:b
line 8:######
line 9:we
line 10:c
line 11:a
line 12:['we', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
line 13:a
line 14:['we', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
line 15:b
line 16:a
line 17:['we', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b']
line 18:#####
line 19:[['a', 'b', 'g', 'b'], ['we', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b']]
```

So I am confused:
Why in the line 6, it prints the word 'g' rather than word 'a'? Because in the line 5 we get a list ['a', 'b', 'g', 'b'], so in the next for loop, it should get the word 'a' at the beginning of this list.

Anyone could tell me why this happend and how to solve my problem? Thank you very much!

[* Attached picture is my code and my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiSAe.png)

Comment: Never modify a list (`document.remove()`) while you are iterating over it (`for word in document:`). Modify a copy or create the copy during iteration (add items to copy you want to keep instead of removing items you don't want).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 2):

Never remove elements from an array while iterating over it, here is a solution to your problem that involves replacing the sub-lists with the desired result (filtering):

```
data = [['a','a','a','b','g','b'],['we','c','a','b','a','a','b','a','b']]
keep_words = ['a']

for i in range(len(data)):
  data[i] = [d for d in data[i] if d in keep_words] # only keep desired data

print(data) # ==> [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments if you mutate a `list` while iterating over it, you will experience these type of [side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/5491375)

An alternative solution would be to take advantage of Python's super fast and readable `list` comprehensions

```
In [33]: [[a for a in l if a in list_b] for l in list_a]
Out[33]: [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
```

Note that as `list_b` grows in size you might want to consider using a `set` which are *much* faster than `list`s with respect to checking for membership. It will also ignore any duplicate entries

```
In [52]: import random

In [73]: import string

In [74]: keep_s = set(['a', 'b', 'e'])

In [75]: keep_l = ['a', 'b', 'e']

# Create a random document -- random choice of 'a'-'f' between 1-100 times
In [78]: def rand_doc():
    ...:     return [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase[:6]) for _ in range(random.randint(1,100))]
    ...:

# Create 1000 random documents
In [79]: docs = [rand_doc() for _ in range(1000)]

In [80]: %timeit [[word for word in doc if word in keep_l] for doc in docs]
4.39 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [81]: %timeit [[word for word in doc if word in keep_s] for doc in docs]
3.16 ms ± 130 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```